# C string.Not getting the desired output. How can I input such number

Tags: c, whitespace, scanf, format-specifiers

What is wrong with the given C code? Why I am unable to get the desired output?
When I Input `"123 + hello = 234"` I expect the output as `"123 hello 234"`.
But the Output is `"123 + hello"`?
Please someone explain the logic with whats wrong and the correct way to get the input.
Also please suggest references for further reading of similar topic.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char str1[11],str2[11],str3[11],ch1,ch2;    
    scanf("%s",str1);
    scanf("%c",&ch1);
    scanf("%s",str2);
    scanf("%c",&ch2);
    scanf("%s",str3);    
    printf("%s %s %s\n",str1,str2,str3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ugh...lots of scanf()s without any success check.

Comment: Use `scanf(" %c",&ch1);` leave 1 space before `" %c"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per your input

```
123 + hello = 234
```

The whitespace matters. The immediate whitespace after `123` goes to `ch1` and `+` to `str2`.

Without having an explicit whitespace in `%c`, it will consider the whitespace in input as *valid* input for *scan*.

Try something like

```
scanf(" %c",&ch1);
       ^
       |
```

Which tells `scanf()` to discard all leading whitespace characters and read the next first *non-whitespace* character, in your case `+`.

<sup>Sidenote: Always check the success ogf `scanf()` by checking the return value. Good Practice</sup>

Comment: But even when i input all in newlines even then the output is not the desired one.

Comment: @ARBY yep, I was expecting this to be lined up next. There, the newline `\n` by pressing `ENTER` joins the party. :-)

Comment: but how does compiler understands wheter that newline or space belongs to string or character? More references needed please.. By the way thankyou very much.

Comment: @ARBY it doesn't understand anything. It _does_ exactly what you're asking to do. Related reading: manual pages for [`scanf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) and look for `format specifiers` or `conversion specifiers`.

Answer (score 1):

Change these lines

```
scanf("%c",&ch1);
scanf("%c",&ch2);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c",&ch1);
scanf(" %c",&ch2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the whitespace character before the control string like this.

```
scanf(" %c",&ch1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to parse your line into the following tokens:

```
{"123", "+", "hello", "=", "234"}
```

And you want to discard "+" and "=".

This could be done in one scanf:

```
scanf("%s + %s = %s", str1, str2, str3);
```

Your mistake was that you assumed space (' ') is how strings are separated.

You will notice in my scanf I was explicit with the delimiters (spaces and +/=).

You should read some more about how scanf uses format strings. This page seems to contain some examples which will hopefully make it more clear for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I did not get the link to the page you mentioned.